# How to sort data by date if the date is specified as a character string?

Tags: c, sorting, structure

The task is as follows:

> Enter a sequence of records with information about some European countries: "Name", "Population", "Main state holiday", "Holiday date". The date of a public holiday is specified with a character string in the form Day Month, for example, 24 August. Print the entered list as a table. Then rearrange the data in calendar order according to the date of the main public holiday and print again

Question:

How can I sort the structure data I entered by date, if the date is specified as a character string?

The idea came to my mind to create an array of strings, where to register all 12 months, then using a loop it goes through each of them and looks for matches with the elements of the array (that is, with months) and assigns, if they match, the index of the element from the array. And then just sort them by index

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define N 25

int main()
{
struct date {
    int day;
    char month1[20];
};

struct country {
    char name[35];
    double population;
    char holl[25];
    struct date date;
}list[N], tmp;

int count, n, i;
char* istr;
char month[12][10] = { "January",  "February",  "March",  "April",  "May",  "June",  "July",  "August",  "September",  "October",  "November",  "December" };

system("chcp 1251");
printf("Count of countrys - ");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
getchar();
printf("\nData: \n");
for (count = 0; count < n; count++) {
    printf(" %d. Name: ", (count + 1));
    gets_s(list[count].name);
    printf(" %d. Population: ", (count + 1));
    scanf_s("%lf", &list[count].population);
    getchar();
    printf(" %d. Holiday: ", (count + 1));
    gets_s(list[count].holl);
    printf(" %d. Late: \n", (count + 1));
    printf("\tDay: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &list[count].date.day);
    getchar();
    printf("\tMonth: ");
    gets_s(list[count].date.month1);
    printf("\n");
    rewind(stdin);
}

printf("\n\t\tTable of data:\n\n");
printf("  Name\t\Population\tHoliday\tDate");
for (count = 0; count < n; count++) {
    printf("\n %d. %s\t\t%.0lf\t\t%s\t\t%d %s", (count + 1), (list + count)->name, list[count].population, (list + count)->holl, list[count].date.day, list[count].date.month1);
}

/*
   for (count = 0; count < n; count++) {
      for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        if (list[count].date.month1 == month[i]) {
            printf("%s ", month[i]);
        }
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        if (list[i].date.month1 > list[j].date.month1) {
            tmp = list[j - 1];
            list[j - 1] = list[j];
            list[j] = tmp; ;
        }
    }
}
*/

return 0;
}
```

There the cycle is not yet completed !!!

P.S. You are kindly requested to do without `qsort` and `strcmp`. I'm a beginner. But if without them there will be nothing at all, then please explain how and what to do

Comment: That's the trick of the task, that you need to enter the month with exactly the word

Comment: By *not* storing the actual month name as a string. It won't be portable, as shown by the edit translating them. January is month `0` in internal represenatation.

Comment: ...to stretch that point, if you were making a chess program, you wouldn't store the game data by the *pictures* of the chess pieces, but by a coded representation. Then the code will work no matter what pictures of the chess pieces are used.

Comment: Maybe you know of any ways to convert a string to a number? Like make a string, for example, `January 24` a number. Do the same with all the other dates, sort them as numbers, but display them on the screen again as a string.

Comment: Yes, you search through the array for a match. January is element `0`. If there is no match found, you don't pass beyond that point: it's an invalid data entry (although you could allow abbreviations).

Comment: Ok, You say that my way is bad. Can you give some hint or hint then how to do it correctly?

Comment: `struct date { int day; int month; };` to store the array index for the month entered. Then print it later with say `printf("%s", monthname[ list[count].date.month ]);`

Comment: Sollpix, where is `gets_s()` defined?  In the standard library annex K it is `char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);` with does not match this code's usage.

Comment: This question needs more focus. I can't tell if the answer needed is how to call `qsort()` or how to compare dates.